# Startup folder shortcut not created

Tags: windows-10, directory, inno-setup, startup

Here's part of my inno setup script:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commonstartup}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
```

When i open the startup folder Win+R and type "shell:startup", there is no such folder created after the setup completed. The normal Program folder is created though. As I understand, to modify commonstartup, requires admin privilege and I have added this entry in Setup, but still not working. Anybody have any idea why and how to fix this?

**EDIT**: ok i tried with {userstartup} then it works. so my question is why the commonstartup one can't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shell:startup` opens user's "startup" folder, not the common one.

To open the common one, use `shell:common startup`.